# How to populate a selectOneChoice control in oracle ADF?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-adf, oracle-fusion-middleware, oracle-fusion-apps

I am using a procedure which has one `IN param(VARCHAR)` and one `OUT param(REF CURSOR)`.
My task is to populate that `REF CURSOR` into a `selectOneChoice` control. I am able to call the procedure in ADF but unable to populate `REF CURSOR` into `selectOneChoice` control.

My Jdeveloper version is 11.1.1.5.0.

Answer (score 0):

Just put the result of your cursor into a List (of a bean) or View Object.
Then use that list to populate your SOC or use the View Object to generate a SOC for you.

Here an example for the bean method:
http://sameh-nassar.blogspot.be/2009/11/filling-selectonechoice-from.html